# Javascript client will not continuously listen with Flask-SocketIO

Tags: javascript, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I am learning websockets with Flask-SocketIO.  The goal is to get have my div continuously populated by a random number every second.  When I run the code below, only the last number appears.  However in the console I see that all arrive at the same time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);

socket.on('pony_update', function(msg){
    console.log("pony update");
    console.log(msg);
    $('#ponies').html(msg.data);
});
```

To update this div

```
<div id="ponies"></div>
```

The "controller" method is

```
@socketio.on('the_ponies', namespace='/test')
def run_numbers(message):
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        x = random.random()
        emit('pony_update', {'data': x}, broadcast=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

It blocks in the thread. Try use `start_background_task` with gevent monkey_patch

```
@socketio.on('pony_update', namespace='/chat')
def run_numbers(message):
    @copy_current_request_context
    def back_work():
        print('start')
        for i in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
            x = random.random()
            print(x)
            emit('my response', {'data': x}, broadcast=True)
    socketio.start_background_task(target=back_work)
```

Please don't forgot to put the monkey patch in top of your file. :)

Comment: Now I want to use `monkey patch` for everything, I love the name!  Could you explain it a bit?  I've never heard of it.

Comment: In following the [Flask-SocketIO docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_socketio.SocketIO.start_background_task) I installed `eventlet`.  Is there version of this solution using `eventlet` instead of `gevent`?

Comment: Raja, I can't get your solution to work, so I opened a request on Flask-SocketIO https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/682